# React Native (Expo) - error: generate-pch command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, reactjs, swift, react-native, expo

Building a React Native Expo app (prebuild on iOS, not using Expo Go) and running into this esoteric error that I can't seem to find elsewhere on the internet.

I'll post it here for the next unlucky React Native dev, and perhaps I'll find a solution and post that too.

`expo run:ios` output:

```
⚠️  (../../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-epxolwjjgmimbdefugnlecrdysuv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/MyProject-Bridging-Header-2vyenlvwppgam.dia:1:1)

Command PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader failed with a nonzero exit code
^ Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error(in target 'MyProject' from project 'MyProject')


❌  error: generate-pch command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)



› 1 error(s), and 1 warning(s)

Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65.
```

Xcode build output:

```
<unknown>:0: error: error opening input file '/Users/jh/Code/MyProject/ios/MyProject/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h' (No such file or directory)
<unknown>:0: error: cannot open file '/Users/jh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-epxolwjjgmimbdefugnlecrdysuv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/MyProject-Bridging-Header-e8n926ydzbc0.dia' for diagnostics emission (No such file or directory)
/Users/jh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-epxolwjjgmimbdefugnlecrdysuv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/MyProject-Bridging-Header-e8n926ydzbc0.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Failed to open diagnostics file") (in target 'MyProject' from project 'MyProject')
Command PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Expo SDK version 44. I'm on a 2022 Mac Studio M1.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found the solution!

I had used `npx react-native-rename` to rename my project, but it didn't rename the Swift bridging header.

It's located in `ios/MyProject/<oldname>-Bridging-Header.h`.

```
    renamed:    ios/MyProject/OldName-Bridging-Header.h -> ios/MyProject/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h
```

While I was doing this, I also discovered that several of my bundle identifiers hadn't been moved over either. Do a codebase search for `com.yourorganization.youroldbundlename` to find & replace those too.

The locations I had to update:

```
./ios/MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
./ios/MyProject/Info.plist
./app.json
```